# Unable to write gradient step in theano for rnn

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, theano, recurrent-neural-network

I have following code in which I convert words to one hot vectors and do a gradient descent in theano using rnn for predicting next words given a sequence of words(basically a language model).

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[68]:

#Importing stuff
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np


# In[69]:

import nltk
import sys
import operator
import csv
import itertools
from utils import *
from datetime import datetime


# In[70]:

#Fixing vocabulary size for one hot vectors and some initialization stuff
v_size = 8000
unknown_token = "UNKNOWN_TOKEN"
start_token = "<s>"
end_token = "</s>"


# In[71]:

#Read data and start preprocessing
with open('reddit-comments-2015-08.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    reader.next()
    sentences = list(itertools.chain(*[nltk.sent_tokenize(x[0].decode('utf-8')) for x in reader]))
    print len(sentences)


# In[72]:

#Tokenize the sentences and add start and end tokens
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(s) for s in sentences]
tokenized_sentences = [[start_token] + s + [end_token] for s in tokenized_sentences]


# In[73]:

#Get word frequencies and use only most frequent words in vocabulary
word_freq = nltk.FreqDist(itertools.chain(*tokenized_sentences))
vocab = word_freq.most_common(v_size-1)


# In[74]:

#Do mapping and reverse mapping
index_to_word = [x[0] for x in vocab]
index_to_word.append(unknown_token)
word_to_index = {w:i for i,w in enumerate(index_to_word)}

#Removing less frequent words
for i, s in enumerate(tokenized_sentences):
    tokenized_sentences[i] = [w if w in word_to_index else unknown_token for w in s]

#Got vectors but they are not one hot
X_train = np.asarray([[word_to_index[w] for w in s[:-1]] for s in tokenized_sentences])
Y_train = np.asarray([[word_to_index[w] for w in s[1:]] for s in tokenized_sentences])
#Preprocessing ends here


# In[75]:

#Take only one sentence for now
X_train = X_train[0]
Y_train = Y_train[0]


# In[76]:

#Make input and output as onehot vectors. This can easily be replaced with vectors generated by word2vec.
X_train_onehot = np.eye(v_size)[X_train]
X = theano.shared(np.array(X_train_onehot).astype('float32'), name = 'X')
Y_train_onehot = np.eye(v_size)[Y_train]
Y = theano.shared(np.array(Y_train_onehot).astype('float32'), name = 'Y')


# In[77]:

#Initializing U, V and W
i_dim = v_size
h_dim = 100
o_dim = v_size

U = theano.shared(np.random.randn(i_dim, h_dim).astype('float32'), name = 'U')
W = theano.shared(np.random.randn(h_dim, h_dim).astype('float32'), name = 'W')
V = theano.shared(np.random.randn(h_dim, o_dim).astype('float32'), name = 'V')


# In[78]:

#forward propagation
s = T.vector('s')

results, updates = theano.scan(lambda x, sm1: T.tanh( T.dot(x, U) + T.dot(sm1, W)),
                               sequences = X_train_onehot,
                               outputs_info = s
                              )
y_hat = T.dot(results, V)

forward_propagation = theano.function(inputs=[s], outputs = y_hat)


# In[80]:

#loss
loss = T.sum(T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(y_hat, Y))


# In[81]:

#Gradients
dw = T.grad(loss, W)
du = T.grad(loss, U)
dv = T.grad(loss, V)


# In[82]:

#BPTT
learning_rate = T.scalar('learning_rate')
gradient_step = theano.function(inputs = [s, learning_rate],
                               updates = (
                                (U, U - learning_rate * du),
                                (V, V - learning_rate * dv),
                                (W, W - learning_rate * dw)
                                )
                               )


# In[ ]:
```

But it keeps throwing error at gradient step. I am posting full code because I don't know which step is affecting the error. The following is the screenshot of error in jupyter notebook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem is with mismatch of types. I had to typecast `du, dv, dw, learning rate` to float32. By default, they are float64.